# Sending FCM notifications without App Server

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is possible to do away with the App Server to send push notifications via FCM ?

Let's assume we set analytics filter, a realtime database and we had some rules, could we create some logic to send automatically notifications without having to resort to an App Server ?

If not possible, would Google Cloud Functions help ? I.e having Firebase trigger some code in Google Cloud Functions that would then trigger some notifications ?

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Send automatically on what condition?

Comment: For example, device proximity to a location (the location could be stored in the realtime database and updated on a regular basis). Or based on some settings (booleans).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you can define a triggering condition by which to send the messages, such as [changes to Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) or other triggers supported by Cloud Functions, you can certainly use Cloud Functions to implement this, making use of the Firebase Admin SDK to [send the message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages).

Comment: OK. So, you confirm that Firebase on its own cannot be used for that, right ? We would either have to have an App Server or Google Cloud Functions in addition to Firebase ?

Comment: Unless you want to put your FCM credentials into your app directly, which is a terrible idea because anyone can then use them, there is no good way to send messages without some backend.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks again.